# Three.js smoke animation with transparent background

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm completely new to three.js,  I'd like the smoke canvas to on top of the image to have a transparent background.
the canvas sits behind the image at the moment, that's why I have this css below.

```
canvas{ 
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top:0px;
    left: 0;
}
```

I don't understand how to remove or to make the black background of the canvas transparent.
Please have a look at my demo below

https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/GxZgZB?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a transparent background you can pass in the alpha parameter to the WebGLRenderer constructor.

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
```

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer

Comment: Thanks, I have errors when I add it. Could you plase try on a codepen? https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/GxZgZB?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scene.background](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/scenes/Scene.background) for this. There is no need to work with an additional HTML element. Just do:

```
scene.background = texture;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvNVmy

Comment: Thanks, could you please have look at this
https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/GxZgZB?editors=1010