# Globejs with R, how to add image as canvas background

Tags: javascript, r, three.js

I did build a globe with globejs in R and I am searching for an option to set an image as canvas background.
I think it is not possible in R directly with bg. I was trying to set the image via body background and set the canvas to transparent. It always gets overridden with black canvas.
Could anyone please tell me where can set the image function as canvas background or where to set a canvas transparency so the HTML body image will be visible.
I did find the possible solutions on the web but I don't know where should I add function or set transparency.
Here is the globe.
https://graphproject.000webhostapp.com/Aitia/Globe/m.html
and the files
https://graphproject.000webhostapp.com/?dir=./Aitia/Globe/m_files/

One side question. Is it hard to set animated rotation of the globe? Where should I put the code with the given file structure?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a similar issue which I answered earlier. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279899/three-js-smoke-animation-with-transparent-background/49280519#49280519](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279899/three-js-smoke-animation-with-transparent-background/49280519#49280519)

Comment: I did set the render but I also had to set "setClearColor". Thanks

Comment: Any idea about the animated rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In THREE JS set:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 ); // the default
```

This makes the canvas animated without background.

For rotation most primitive way is set a translation to the render/animate function:

```
function render() {

                if ( mesh ) {
                    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01; /// or mesh.rotateX(0.01)

                }

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin for your help. Could you be so kind and let me know where should I put this function? In globe.js?

Comment: renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 ) to globe.js line 20 (you have  r.setClearColor(0x00ff0000, 0);)

Comment: If I change that it does not work, the globe is not visible.

Comment: 0x00ff0000 is not a valid color value at first, you have mess in render and animate functions. Your render function is called in event onmousemove, then again in body by itself, you should use animationframe. What is mesh variable in render loop? You have to solve a proper code first. Try use some examples http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/09/16/how-to-make-the-earth-in-webgl/

Comment: This was done via R package leaflet. I don't know JS and I usually change small obvious parts of the code which are generated mostly by different types of software. I think animation is too complicated for me but at least transparency is working.